# Calculate the probabilities by simulation in R programming

Tags: r, statistics, probability

You have all the black cards from a normal deck, I have all the red cards. We each choose one card from our half decks - the highest card wins. But I have managed to sneak out and throw away your 9 Of Clubs! Simulate 1000 games - how many did I win? (Ace is low.)

```
reds = rep(1:13, 2)
n = 1000
sum(sample(reds[-9], n, rep = T) < sample(reds, n, rep = T))
```

This is my code, I want to show the how many times I did win when simulate 1000 games if the 9 of clubs from black card removed.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you just need to divide the total of winnings by the total number of simulations

```
sum(sample(reds[-9], n, rep = T) < sample(reds, n, rep = T))/n
```